# Passing post data for windows.popup

Tags: javascript, jsp, tomcat

A popup window is opened using window.popup Is it possible send post data to the popup page?
I am working in tomcat + jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `target` attribute of `<form>` to POST data to a popup. If you don't need to open the window explicitly using `window.open`, you can simply use an arbitrary window name as your target and the browser should POST the data to a new window. Whether a new popup opens or not depends on your browser. If you need to explicitly open the popup with `window.open`, I think you can still target that window with the target attribute once the popup is open.

```
var win = window.open("placeholder.htm", "mypopup"); // optional step

<form action="doit.jsp" method="post" target="mypopup">
```

Comment: Excellent! Is it possible to control the windows size of the popup thru target option?

Comment: No, it's not possible to do that through target. But you could post the desired dimensions to your popup and then resize (with JS) the window based on those parameters.

Comment: the parameter value can easily be changed during a post, if anyone wants to do it. see tamperData plugin for firefox